# Installing JavaMail 1.4.7 on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, smtp, jakarta-mail

I want to install *JavaMail* to establish an *SMTP* connection between two clients (and if you know other ways of establishing that connection, please let me know). I'm using Eclipse IDE to run the project that needs *JavaMail*.

It appears that 1.4.7 is the latest version. I followed the instructions on the [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/hackystat/wiki/InstallingJavaMail) page, but got stuck on one step. I have to copy `mail.jar` to `.../lib/ext`, but I don't know where to find the right spot. I found this [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=908567) thread according to which `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06` is where I put mail.jar. That is not the case with my Ubuntu. Instead I have a whole series of similar directories:

`java-1. ...` directories, `java-6-openjdk`, `java-6-openjdk-common`, `java-6-openjdk-i386`, and `java-7-openjdk-i386`.

and only some of them have `/lib/ext`.

My question is:

Which directory's `/lib/ext` should I go to and copy `mail.jar`?

Comment: Should be asked on [ubuntu.se]

Comment: @b__ : No one on AskUbuntu responded.

Comment: Well, answer some Questions, gain some reputation and put bounties (usually works). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Note that the [latest version of JavaMail is 1.5.1](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: Since I'm using Eclipse IDE to run my project, I believe it would work if I took javax.mail.jar to the lib directory of my project instead of taking it to `/usr/lib/jvm/someJavaDirectory/lib/ext`, and then refreshing my project and building a path to the jar file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look which Java installation is the default one for your system. So issue a

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Now go to that directory (the one with * shoud be the default) and put the `mail.jar` into `lib/ext`. Works for my on my Fedora:-)

Comment: The one marked with a star is `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_7u45/bin/java`, and there `java` is not a directory. I also went to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_7u45/lib`, but there is not `/ext`. What do I do now?

Comment: I would try to create that directory and just drop the jar there

Comment: So, just to make sure, I go to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_7u45/bin`, and there I create `/java` with `/lib/ext` in it, correct?

Comment: I tried 'sudo mkdir -p java' in the JDK directory, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try this - now in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_7u45` - `sudo mkdir -p lib/ext`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41436/discussion-between-andrey-and-petr-mensik)